# Order posts alphabetically: how to set order=asc in mysql query?

Tags: posts, functions, query-posts, mysql, order

I have this `function`:

```
  global $wpdb;
  // adjust the query to fit your needs  
  $posts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE
    post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND
    post_title LIKE %s",
```

How do I set the order => ASC in this query? I want to show my `posts` alphabetically...

Comment: You could look at the MySQL docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html As written, this is a pure SQL question and would be off topic per the [faq](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use WordPress [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)?

You can add the parameter [orderby](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Latest_posts_ordered_by_title) => 'title' as you want.

```
$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'order'          => 'ASC', 
    'orderby'        => 'title' 
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

print_r($posts);
```

If you want the sql you can just add `ORDER BY post_title`:

```
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts 
WHERE post_type = 'post' 
AND post_status = 'publish' 
AND post_title LIKE %s
ORDER BY post_title
```

Comment: It is not showing me the posts if I use ORDER BY post_title... When I remove it, it is showing the posts. That's weird. I am not using the first solution, because this is a function where I have to use MySQL.